# Selecting tuples of lines from an Sqlite table and sorting the tuples efficiently

Tags: sqlite, sorting, indexing, sql-order-by

I have a very big table with four columns

```
+-----+-------+-----+-----+
| nr  | lemId | cId | bId |
+-----+-------+-----+-----+
| ... |       |     |     |
| 611 |    19 |   2 |   3 |
| 611 |    19 |   3 |   3 |
| 611 |    19 |   4 |   3 |
| 611 |    19 |   5 |   3 |
| 611 |    19 |   6 |   3 |
| 611 |    19 |   1 |   3 |
| 612 |    19 |  18 |   3 |
| 612 |    19 |   7 |   3 |
| 612 |    19 |   8 |   3 |
| 613 |    19 |   1 | 205 |
| 613 |    19 |  18 | 205 |
| 614 |    19 |   2 | 224 |
| 615 |    19 |   2 | 249 |
| ... |       |     |     |
| 659 | 20    | 14  | 1434|
| 659 | 20    | 15  | 1434|
| 659 | 20    | 16  | 1434|
| 659 | 20    | 17  | 1434|
| 660 | 20    | 14  | 1483|
| 660 | 20    | 15  | 1483|
| 648 | 20    | 1   | 205 |
| 648 | 20    | 18  | 205 |
| 649 | 20    | 2   | 249 |
| 649 | 20    | 3   | 249 |
| 649 | 20    | 8   | 249 |
| 650 | 20    | 4   | 279 |
| 650 | 20    | 5   | 279 |
| ... |       |     |     |
+-----+-------+-----+-----+
```

For *n* lemIds (lem0, lem1, ...), I want to select a tuple of *n* different rows from the table with the following properties:

- row0: lemId = lem0,
- row1: lemId = lem1,

  - etc.
- all *n* rows must have the same cId
- all *n* rows must have different bId

This can be done with a multiple select.
Here an example for two lemIds (19 and 20)

```
SELECT  l0.cId,l0.bId,l1.bId
    FROM ltc AS l0, ltc AS l1
    WHERE
        l0.cId=l1.cId  AND l0.bId!=l1.bId
        AND l0.lemId = 19
        AND l1.lemId = 20
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Up to here all goes well and fast.

I need to get the result rows in an order that mixes the cIds, that means, if there are for example 20 different cIds in the results, I need those different result tuples first before the same cId repeats. 
Put differently, if there are say 20 different cIds (say from 1 to 20) in the say 1000 result tuples of the form (cId, bId0, bId1), I need to get the results as follows:

```
(1, …)
(2, …)
…
(20, …)
(1, …)
(2, …)
...
```

For that reason, I’ve precomputed a value when inserting the information: *nr*. When sorting by this value, it gives me the desired order:

```
 order by
  l0.nr asc,
  l1.nr asc
```

The problem is that this sorting is extremely slow and it seems impossible to use any kind of indexing as suggested in the answer of [How to make Sqlite use an index for ordering on multiple columns in the case of multiple selection from the same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509695/how-to-make-sqlite-use-an-index-for-ordering-on-multiple-columns-in-the-case-of), at least using this way of querying. Moreover, the query time seems to grow exponentially with the size *n* of the tuple, possibly because of the construction of a *temp B-tree* in the sorting process.

Is there some way of obtaining the result efficiently, possibly even without using *nr*?

---

Here some unsorted results from the above query:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| cId | b0  | b1  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|   1 |   3 | 205 |
|   2 |   3 | 249 |
|   3 |   3 | 249 |
|   4 |   3 | 279 |
|   4 |   3 | 321 |
|   5 |   3 | 279 |
|   5 |   3 | 321 |
|   6 |   3 | 321 |
|   6 |   3 | 386 |
|   7 |   3 | 321 |
|   7 |   3 | 386 |
|   8 |   3 | 249 |
|  18 |   3 | 205 |
|   1 |   3 | 205 |
|   2 |   3 | 249 |
|   3 |   3 | 249 |
|   4 |   3 | 279 |
|   4 |   3 | 321 |
|   5 |   3 | 279 |
|   5 |   3 | 321 |
|   6 |   3 | 321 |
|   6 |   3 | 386 |
|   7 |   3 | 321 |
|   7 |   3 | 386 |
|   8 |   3 | 249 |
|  18 |   3 | 205 |
|   1 | 205 |   3 |
|   1 | 205 |   3 |
|  18 | 205 |   3 |
|  18 | 205 |   3 |
|   2 | 224 |   3 |
|   2 | 224 |   3 |
|   2 | 224 | 249 |
|   2 | 249 |   3 |
|   2 | 249 |   3 |
|   3 | 249 |   3 |
|   3 | 249 |   3 |
|   8 | 249 |   3 |
|   8 | 249 |   3 |
|   4 | 279 |   3 |
|   4 | 279 |   3 |
|   4 | 279 | 321 |
|   5 | 279 |   3 |
|   5 | 279 |   3 |
|   5 | 279 | 321 |
|   4 | 321 |   3 |
|   4 | 321 |   3 |
|   4 | 321 | 279 |
|   5 | 321 |   3 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

---

CL's answer is correct and I managed to redo my database looking for vocables (base forms shared by different lemmas) and in this way use what CL proposed. This allowed me to avoid:

```
    WHERE ltc2.lemId in (21, 22)
```

and have instead

```
    WHERE ltc2.vocabId = 11
```

What I ended up doing is first look up the vocabId with a separate query (in Python!!!) before doing the complex query that CL proposed. Moveover, this query grows by about a dozen lines with each additional query term. But still: This way it became very fast.

So there is one follow-up question if I may: The fact that even a single

```
    WHERE ltc2.lemId in (21)
```

is so much slower than a

```
    WHERE ltc2.lemId = 21
```

makes me wonder: Is this a bug or a feature?

More precisely: Do you expect the same performance drop to happen with any database system, or is this something specific to Sqlite?

Comment: What is the desired output for the example data?

Comment: The desired output is simply the tuples (cId, bId0, bId1) that fulfill the conditions. I have thousands of results, and I only need 10 at a time. - sorry I edited your comment instead of posting my own :-(

Comment: Which 10? If there are 20 different `cId`s, could the result be just ten random `bId` values?

Comment: Yes, it could be any random bId values as long as bId0 and bId1 (and bId2, etc) are all different (and the cIds arrive in the indicated iterating order).

Comment: The example data is incomplete. Add some rows with `lemId` = 20, and a table with the desired result.

Comment: Ok. I've added the information! Thank you!

Comment: The output does not match the example data. (Executing the query on the example data does not output anything.)

Comment: Now it should give some results.

Comment: Do you need *all* allowed combinations of `bId` values?

Comment: Yes. But if you find a way of giving me **one** combination of bIds per cId that could already be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query returns one combination of `bId`s per `cId`:

```
SELECT cId,
       bId AS bId19,
       (SELECT min(bId)
        FROM ltc AS ltc1
        WHERE ltc1.lemId = 20
          AND ltc1.cId = ltc0.cId
          AND ltc1.bId != ltc0.bId
       ) AS bId20
FROM ltc AS ltc0
WHERE lemId = 19
  AND bId20 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY bId19, cId
```

Using a subquery instead of a join is the easiest method of ensuring that only one combination is computed.

It is not possible to refer to an expression in the SELECT clause from within another expression in the same SELECT clause, so if you have three or more `bId`s, you need to introduce more subqueries:

```
SELECT cId,
       bId19,
       bId20,
       (SELECT min(bId)
        FROM ltc AS ltc2
        WHERE ltc2.lemId = 21
          AND ltc2.cId = ltc0.cId
          AND ltc2.bId != ltc0.bId19  -- and/or bId20?
       ) AS bId21
FROM (SELECT cId,
             bId AS bId19,
             (SELECT min(bId)
              FROM ltc AS ltc1
              WHERE ltc1.lemId = 20
                AND ltc1.cId = ltc0.cId
                AND ltc1.bId != ltc0.bId
             ) AS bId20
      FROM ltc AS ltc0
      WHERE lemId = 19) AS ltc0
WHERE bId20 IS NOT NULL
  AND bId21 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY bId19, cId
```

With an index on `(lemId, bId, cId)`, no sorting is necessary.
An index on `(lemId, cId, bId)` would speed up the subquery lookup, but not by very much.

---

As for returning all combinations: I see no mechanism to implement the 'mixing' that could be more efficient than the precomputed `nr`.

Any query must search rows by doing lookups on `lemId` first, so to be able to use an index for sorting, you need an index on `(lemId, nr)`. However, this allows to speed up sorting only on *one* `nr` column, and only with the [partial sorting support](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#partialsort) in SQLite 3.8.5 or later, so this might or might not be fast enough for you.
(Just use your original query with multiple joins.)

When the lookup on `ltc0.lemId` uses multiple IDs (`lemId IN (1,2)`) or a subquery (`lemId IN (SELECT ...)`), index-sorting by `nr` is not possible at all.
Due to the large number of returned rows, the sorting will then be slow.

Comment: The answer is exactly correct in every point I could verify (all except the 3.8.5 version part) but I fail so far to generalize it to 3 lemIds: I need to compare ltc0.bId!=ltc2.bId and as the subquery can only give back one single value, I don't manage to use this idea in the general case of a search of _n_ lemIds. Any ideas on that? Thanks!!!