# How to use comparison operator to filter data in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database dictionary have about 50,000 records. I created indexes and used them to filter the data.  But when I tried using Like operator, indexes not working and it make my application slow when I tried input key to filter in searchview if did not find data in database (data is load into listview and i also using asynctask). And i think the reason for that is indexes are not working with `Like` operator. So I tried to change my select query by comparison operator. But it is not working with my thinking. I want it working such as like but it's not. So anyone know what is my wrong in select query and how i can fix it?

Here is my select query using comparison operator

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM '"+TABLE_ENG_VIE+"' WHERE word >= '"+keyFilter+"'  LIMIT 20 OFFSET '"+offset+"'";
```

Here is my select query using LIKE operator

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM '"+TABLE_ENG_VIE+"' WHERE word LIKE '"+keyFilter+"%' LIMIT 20 OFFSET '"+offset+"'";
```

Thanks for reading my question and so sorry if I explain not cleared because my english is not good. Thanks again and good luck for you.

Comment: try "glob" instead of "like"

Comment: @pskink thanks you bro. u save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

change your query to below, according to me you have mistaken while writing `LIKE` condition

```
String qry = "SELECT * FROM '" + TABLE_ENG_VIE + "' WHERE word LIKE '%" + keyFilter + "%';";
```

Comment: I think your query to filter any data that have keyword equal to keyFilter. But i just want filter the data that have characters begin by "keyFilter". So I use 'keyFilter%'. And if you use Like operator, the indexes will not working. It make the database lost a few second to filter.

Comment: sorry i just forgot to add that variable, please check updated answer@XiaoKing

Comment: Your query look similiar as: SELECT * FROM anh_viet WHERE word like   '%lov%' . The results for select query above are all words have "lov" character as: beloved, clove, glove and so on...But I want my result must are: love, loveable and something like that.

Comment: tthan use SELECT * FROM anh_viet WHERE word like 'lov%';

Comment: But I just want filter the word begin with keyFilter :(. And if i use your query to filter. It also loss a few second to filter in database because Like operation not using indexes :(.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509695/how-to-make-sqlite-use-an-index-for-ordering-on-multiple-columns-in-the-case-of

Comment: is this helpeful ?@XiaoKing

Comment: thanks you bro, but my problem is resolved by using GLOB in SQLite :).

Comment: **glob** will give you result if having exact word.

Comment: glob working such as like but it distinguish between lowercase and upercase.

Comment: okay that is better.